# Why aren't English "house" and Latin "casa" considered cognates? Latin 'c' corresponds to English 'h', and Latin 's' corresponds to English 's'

Tags: etymology

So, why are linguists so sure that Latin "casa" and English "house" are false cognates? Latin 'c' does correspond regularly to English 'h' (as in "centum"-"hundred"), and Latin 's' corresponds regularly to English 's' (as in "sex"-"six" and "septem"-"seven").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because English *ou* can't correspond to Latin *a*. There are actually a bunch of sources for *ou* in Modern English, so lets turn to Old English: *house* continues OE *hūs* (not a reconstruction, this word is attested). Some other OE words with *ū*, with Latin comparanda:

| Old English | Latin |
| --- | --- |
| *brūcan* 'to use, enjoy' | *fruor* 'to enjoy' |
| *būan* 'to dwell' | *fuī* 'to become' |
| *cūþ* 'known' | *nōtus* |
| *hlūd* 'loud' | *inclutus* 'famous' |
| *hlūtor* 'clear, pure' | *cluō* 'to clean, purge' |
| *mūs* 'mouse' | *mūs* |
| *mūþ* 'mouth' | *mentum* 'chin' |
| *sū* 'sow (female pig)' | *sūs* 'pig' |
| *sūcan* 'to suck' | *sūgō* 'to suck' |
| *sūl* 'plough' | *sulcus* 'furrow' |
| *þū* 'you (sg.)' | *tū* |
| *þūma* 'thumb' | *tumor* 'swelling' |
| *ūs* 'us' | *nos* |
| *ūt* 'out' | *usque* 'until' |

Most of these aren't exact formal matches, and particularly verbs are always especially difficult because you can have different ablaut grades and invariably have analogical levelling going on, and most Latin verb endings start with vowels and in Latin long vowels shorten before other vowels (as in *fruor*, where the *u* was originally long, as you can see in derivatives like *frūmen* and *frūmentum*), but I hope you'll agree it's at least plausible the roots are the same on these—proving it more fully would take more space and time than is reasonable here.
(Note also that English, for its part, sometimes does weird things around *n*: *cūþ* vs. *nōtus* (both from PIE **ǵn̥h₃tos*, though you need more than these two forms to reconstruct that), *mūþ* vs. *mentum* (compare Dutch *mond* 'mouth'), *ūs* vs. *nos* (which do have different ablaut grades); this is a well-understood phenomenon, but it's one you need to be aware exists when you're trying to reconstruct words.)

To make this case more rigorously you'd have to look at far more words in more languages (and also the earliest forms of words, so you'd really want to reconstruct Proto-Germanic first), but as a general impression you can at least see that OE *ū* almost always correlates (I won't say corresponds, because again, most of these words aren't exact matches) to *u*, long or short, in Latin, and never to *a*.
For completeness' sake we could do this exercise again to see what Latin *a* does correspond to in Germanic, but just take my word that it's *a*: *father* vs. *pater*, &c.

So even if the origins of neither *house* nor *casa* are perfectly clear, we *are* able to say with a great degree of certainty that they aren't cognate. **Always look at the entire word, not just the consonants that happen to match.**